# Flutter BLoC complex list yield ErrorState

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

There is this Flutter BLoC example of complex list - https://github.com/felangel/bloc/tree/master/examples/flutter_complex_list

While everything in here makes sense, I am struggling to understand how can I yield `ErrorState` after clicking on trash icon.

Comment: Do you have a reason why you want this or you are just experimenting on how to trigger different states?

Comment: @mkobuolys Yeah, I actually need this. I have a list like this and on each item there is a button. However, I would like to show user that the response from pressing that button can be failure. So it should go like this: User presses button -> button is now circular progress -> either a success state is yielded (+ dialog alert is shown) or errorstate is yielded (+ dialog alert is shown). While I understand how to yield Success and keep list as is, I am not sure how I can emit Error state and keep list as is.

Comment: So just define your failure condition inside BLoC (error while calling API, validation failed, whatever) and if that condition is true, yield the error state - the yield part is exactly the same whether you are yielding a success state or an errors state.

Comment: @mkobuolys haha, oh my god, I can't believe I missed that. Exactly what I will do, thank you very much